# Is an uniqueidentifier data type in SQL the same as an autonumber in Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm creating a database using SQL for the first time and was wondering if a uniqueidentifier data type is the same as an autonumber in MS Access? If it isn't can anyone show me how to make SQL automatically create an integer value for a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniqueidentifier is a 16 byte GUID. Represented as a 32 character hex string.

Int is an integer.

To create a table with an integer as a primary key in MS SQL like such:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName(
YourIDColumn INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1))
```

I have taken the liberty in seeding your identity key starting at 1, and the auto increment by 1. Note that this is also the default in SQL but I have specified it here for clarity sake. The statement will also create a primary key (and by proxy a clustered index) on that column.

Comment: The `IDENTITY` keyword is what gives the auto-increment feature.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. I just wasn't sure how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: `uniqueidentifier` is **not** a 32 character anything. It's a 16-byte GUID. If you *convert* it into a string, a conventional representation might be as 32 hex digits. That doesn't *make* it such a string. Don't confuse *data* with *representations*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever fair enough, I will update the post to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. In Access, you have to use Autonumber or Long. Not String.

Then, in the lower pane of the design window, specify *Field Size*: Replication-ID

Now the field will hold a true GUID.

Comment: Autonumber is not a hexadecimal guid.

Comment: Why do you think so? I have used it several times, and it completely compatible with _uniqueidentifier_ in SQL Server. Please check it out and remove your downvote. See the comment from @Damien above.

Comment: It does not match the user request to have an integer value that auto increments.

Comment: That is correct, but nevertheless you have to specify either Autonumber or Long _and_ Replication-ID in the table designer if you wish to have a field in Access with a data type (GUID) directly compatible with uniqueidentifier of SQL Server.

Comment: Fair enough, I understand what you are saying, but that doesn't answer the question specifically. If you use Replication-ID and Autonumber it does become interchangeable with uniqueidentifier. I will change my vote when SO let's me (1 hour...).

Comment: OK, got your point. I've edited my answer to clarify the confusing idiosyncrasy of Access.